# Visual Studio не видит приложение Django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Проблема в следующем:
после добавления нового приложения в проект Django (правой кнопкой мыши: Добавить -> Приложение Django), то проект не видит его.
Не могу понять почему. Даже, если присмотреться, открываю два файла apps.py из, казалось бы, идентичных приложениий, то в первом файле студия подсвечивает слова совсем иначе, чем в другом. Может это как-то влияет? Как будто не откомпилирован, чтоли.
[image: apps.py intellisense error]
Ну и, соответственно, ошибка при запуске, мол

> Cannot import 'about'. Check that
>   'samplesite.about.apps.aboutConfig.name' is correct.

[image: Error when running]

Comment: А в installed_apps в settings.py вы его добавили?

Comment: Кстати, как вы его запускаете? (Какая строка запуска, из какой директории?)

Comment: @Александр, похоже всё-таки это сбоит сама студия. Выгрузил её полностью, плюс ещё, там есть такая опция, как "Очистить проект". Заново запустил и работает. Причём, добавлять приложения в INSTALLED_APPS необязательно, работает тоже.
В целом, в этой IDE работать круто, хотя я совсем новичок и только начал.